# Disponibilizar um .JS para outros sites

Tags: javascript

Estou iniciando nesta linguagem, e preciso de uma orientação...
Preciso realizar um código javascript que deverá ficar em meu servidor e ser disponibilizado para o cliente apenas o .JS, afim de guardar o código para mim...
Eu iria verificar qual é o cliente pode utilizar dando a ele uma senha codificada (tipo token) e verificar se a url dele é autorizada...
O exemplo explicar melhor...
Esse seria o código que o cliente colocaria em seu site

```js
<script src="https://meusite.com.br/cotacao_dolar.js?token=3c780698c2cf59ca7ae5130fdc2016ce4af736a4"></script>
```

E o código no meu servidor puxaria esses dois valores (token e a URL)...
Como posso puxar esses valores para o meu script?
Alguém exemplos ou modelos para eu seguir?
Att,

Answer (score 0):

Esses parâmetros estarão disponíveis via GET. No seu script, você usaria algo assim:

```js
// Vai armazenar o endereço da requisição, no caso, https://meusite.com.br/cotacao_dolar.js?token=3c780698c2cf59ca7ae5130fdc2016ce4af736a4
var url_string = window.location.toString();

var url = new URL(url_string);
var token = url.searchParams.get("token");

// Retorna o token
console.log(token);

// Retorna o domínio
console.log(url.host);

// Retorna o protocolo + domínio
console.log(url.origin);

// Retorna o nome do script
console.log(url.pathname);
```

Foi respondida essa pergunta no StackOverflow em Inglês, o link do crédito é esse aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995

Nesse link também há uma segunda opção de script para browsers antigos.

**EDIT**
Quando você disponibiliza o script para outra pessoa usar no site dela, ela ainda pode abrir ele e ver o código. Para impedir que a pessoa consiga ler o código, você pode ofuscar o código.

Sites como esse: https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/
Permitem que você coloque um código JS e ofusque ele em vários níveis.
O código que eu postei de exemplo, quando é ofuscado, tem um output parecido com esse abaixo (e ainda continua funcionando normalmente):

```js
var _0x3456=['toString','searchParams','log','host','origin','pathname','length','constructor','debugger'];(function(a,d){var b=function(b){while(--b){a['push'](a['shift']());}};var c=function(){var a={'data':{'key':'cookie','value':'timeout'},'setCookie':function(b,h,i,e){e=e||{};var c=h+'='+i;var a=0x0;for(var a=0x0,f=b['length'];a<f;a++){var g=b[a];c+=';\x20'+g;var d=b[g];b['push'](d);f=b['length'];if(d!==!![]){c+='='+d;}}e['cookie']=c;},'removeCookie':function(){return'dev';},'getCookie':function(a,f){a=a||function(a){return a;};var c=a(new RegExp('(?:^|;\x20)'+f['replace'](/([.$?*|{}()[]\/+^])/g,'$1')+'=([^;]*)'));var e=function(a,b){a(++b);};e(b,d);return c?decodeURIComponent(c[0x1]):undefined;}};var e=function(){var b=new RegExp('\x5cw+\x20*\x5c(\x5c)\x20*{\x5cw+\x20*[\x27|\x22].+[\x27|\x22];?\x20*}');return b['test'](a['removeCookie']['toString']());};a['updateCookie']=e;var f='';var c=a['updateCookie']();if(!c){a['setCookie'](['*'],'counter',0x1);}else if(c){f=a['getCookie'](null,'counter');}else{a['removeCookie']();}};c();}(_0x3456,0x1a7));var _0x6345=function(a,c){a=a-0x0;var b=_0x3456[a];return b;};var _0x1da1b0=function(){var a=!![];return function(d,b){var c=a?function(){if(b){var a=b['apply'](d,arguments);b=null;return a;}}:function(){};a=![];return c;};}();var _0x5d307c=_0x1da1b0(this,function(){var b=function(){return'\x64\x65\x76';},c=function(){return'\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77';};var d=function(){var a=new RegExp('\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x5c\x29\x20\x2a\x7b\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x2e\x2b\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x3b\x3f\x20\x2a\x7d');return!a['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](b['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};var e=function(){var a=new RegExp('\x28\x5c\x5c\x5b\x78\x7c\x75\x5d\x28\x5c\x77\x29\x7b\x32\x2c\x34\x7d\x29\x2b');return a['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](c['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());};var a=function(a){var b=~-0x1>>0x1+0xff%0x0;if(a['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']('\x69'===b)){f(a);}};var f=function(b){var c=~-0x4>>0x1+0xff%0x0;if(b['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']((!![]+'')[0x3])!==c){a(b);}};if(!d()){if(!e()){a('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');}else{a('\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66');}}else{a('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');}});_0x5d307c();var _0x335e95=window['location'][_0x6345('0x0')]();var _0x33f763=new URL(_0x335e95);var _0x31ae0e=_0x33f763[_0x6345('0x1')]['get']('token');console[_0x6345('0x2')](_0x31ae0e);console[_0x6345('0x2')](_0x33f763[_0x6345('0x3')]);console[_0x6345('0x2')](_0x33f763[_0x6345('0x4')]);console[_0x6345('0x2')](_0x33f763[_0x6345('0x5')]);var _0xd3172e=function(){function a(b){if((''+b/b)[_0x6345('0x6')]!==0x1||b%0x14===0x0){(function(){}[_0x6345('0x7')](_0x6345('0x8'))());}else{(function(){}[_0x6345('0x7')](_0x6345('0x8'))());}a(++b);}try{a(0x0);}catch(a){}};_0xd3172e();
```

Comment: Obrigado, então a ideia ainda não está completa... Preciso de uma ajuda para poder elaborar a ideia... é o seguinte... Vou fazer modais para serem colocados em um site externo, que será verificado pelo token se está liberado ou não este site... Até ae, o seu código já me ajudou... Agora o que preciso fazer é dar ao cliente um código script para ser colocado em seu site, exemplo "<script src="http://www.teste.com/publish.js?token=0893287988"></script>". Mas NINGUEM deveria ver o código... os modais estou fazendo em javascript, mas atualmente, a pessoa abre o link acima e visualiza todo o código

Comment: Entendi! Infelizmente, a pessoa vai ver o código, porque o javascript não impede isso. O que você pode fazer é "camuflar" o código javascript, para que ele não consiga ser lido por uma pessoa comum. Vou editar a minha resposta principal.

Comment: Entendi, perfeitamente, vou ofuscar... é a melhor opção vista até agora